# How to display pyramid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have 1 array like this:

```js
var array = ['1', '3', '4', '10', '2', '5', '9', '7', '8', '6'];
array = array.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b) - parseInt(a));
var length = 4;
var count = 0;
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= length - i; j++) {
    output += `  ${array[count]}`;
    count++;
  }
  console.log(output);
  output = "";
}
```

that's my code, but It's not my expected result.
my expected  result is as shown below:

```
10 9 8 7
6 5 4 
3 2 
1
```

Comment: is the array given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Provided array length always should be sum of *Natural Numbers*(1+2+3+4...)**

**Natural Number :** 1,2,3,4,5...

**Few valid array lengths :** 3,6,10,15,21...

**Ex.**

```
var array = ['1', '3', '4', '10', '2', '5', '9', '7', '8', '6'];
```

```
var array = ['1', '3', '4', '2', '5', '6'];
```

```
var array = ['15', '1', '3', '13', '4', '10', '2', '14', '5', '9', '12', '7', '8', '6', '11'];
```

```
function generatePyramid(arr) {
    var pyramidSize = getPyramidSize(arr.length),
        sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) { return parseInt(b) - parseInt(a) }),
        count = 0;
    if (pyramidSize == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < pyramidSize; i++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < pyramidSize - i; j++) {
            row += " " + sortedArray[count];
            count++;
        }
        console.log(row);
    }
}

function getPyramidSize(size) {
    var sum = 0,
        isNotSumOfNaturalNumbers = -1;
    for (var i = 1; sum < size; i++) {

        sum += i;
        if (sum == size) { return i };
    }
    console.error("Error: Length of provided array should be sum of Natural Numbers(Ex. 1+2+3...)");
    console.warn("Next valid array length : ", sum);
    return isNotSumOfNaturalNumbers;
}

//Define any array and call the method
var array = ['15', '1', '3', '13', '4', '10', '2', '14', '5', '9', '12', '7', '8', '6', '11'];
generatePyramid(array);
```

**OutPut**

```
15 14 13 12 11
10 9 8 7
6 5 4
3 2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generatePyramid() {
    var totalNumberofRows = 5;
    var output="";
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            output+=j + "     ";
        }
        console.log(output);
        output="";
    }
}
```